# SQL Server : does adding OR clauses to WHERE condition slows query?

Tags: sql-server

The only additional condition to topic title is that query is using `LIKE`s.

Is there a difference in performance between query with one condition and with a hundred?
Table has smth about 10k rows and field type is `varchar(550)`.

e.g.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE field LIKE '%value%'
```

and

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE field LIKE '%val_1%' 
   OR field LIKE '%val_2%' 
   OR field LIKE '%val_3%' 
   OR field LIKE '%val_4%' 
   OR field LIKE '%val_5%'
   ... 
   OR field LIKE '%val_100%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there will be a difference.

If the conditions are all on the same column, the difference will be small (as it will only increase the query cost by a few CPU cycles).

If the conditions are on different columns, the difference can potentially be huge considering, for example, if they are all part of the same index. If you deal with other conditions then LIKE '%... (which results in SCANs), the uniqueness of the columns, the probable difference in selectivity, among other things, impact the query cost.

Comment: Thanks. Yes all substrings are compared to one column. I noticed that query ran a bit slower when additional OR-clauses were added. It wasn't much: from avarage 0.2 seconds to average 0.4 seconds but it made me wonder whether it is a server load issus or query just became slower.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that more OR conditions make the query text larger (and if you are on a dialup, can take longer to transmit). Also, more OR conditions can result in more resulting rows (which will take time to transfer over the network). Use the query plan to see the actual number of IO and CPU consumed for both the queries. Also, 'Include Client statistics' to get more of a query profile...

Answer (score 1):

In your example, I would expect there is a performance impact. How significant will depend on your data.

Using the "%" at the beginning of your search will trigger and Index Scan at best (if your column is indexed). The more terms you search, the more effort the machine has to put into the Index Scan.

In the case of the "or" clause, your search just has to hit one value, so it might also depend on the frequency in the data of the values you are searching.  So a dataset with no matching values will take significantly longer then perhaps a data set where there are frequent values.

Comment: Hmm. Good to know this. Going to check if field is indexed.

Comment: Realistically an index may not make that much of a difference on 10K rows, particularly if your field doesn't have a lot of repeating values.